# C++ Valgrind invalid delete dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, dynamic-arrays

```
int* doubleArray(int *ptr, int n){
delete[]  ptr; 
int size = 2*n;
int * tmp = new int[size];
ptr = tmp;
delete [] tmp;
return ptr;
}
```

when I run this code to double the size of the array it ends in a Segmentation fault and when I run Valgrind it displays this message:

```
Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==96889==    at 0x4A08634: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==96889==    by 0x400C9E: doubleArray(int*, int) (debug.cpp:55)
==96889==    by 0x400B58: main (debug.cpp:34)
==96889==  Address 0xfff000300 is on thread 1's stack
==96889==  in frame #0, created by operator delete[](void*)
```

and here is the program output:

```
75 0 760281175 52 1621398400  
*** Error in `./debug': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffd60a49258 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3427c77a8d]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x5cd)[0x3427c83d2d]
./debug[0x400cd8]
./debug[0x400b99]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x3427c20700]
./debug[0x400a29]
```

here I initialize the first array called from the main

```
int* ptr = initArray(n);

int* initArray(int n){
int arr[n];
int *ptr = arr;
return ptr;
}
```

any ideas on how to fix this leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to memory that you just deallocated by calling `delete`.  So when you access the memory address returned by this function you are probably getting a segmentation violation.

You should probably change your code to the following

```
int* doubleArray(int *ptr, int n){
    int* new_array = new int[n << 1]; // n << 1 == 2*n
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        new_array[i] = ptr[i];
    }
    delete[]  ptr; 
    return new_array;
}
```

This will allocate memory, copy over the old array and return a pointer to an array that is twice the capacity of the old one.

Comment: I changed it to that and I am still getting a memory leak:

==8065== 40 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==8065==    at 0x4A077FD: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8065==    by 0x400CB6: doubleArray(int*, int) (debug.cpp:55)
==8065==    by 0x400B58: main (debug.cpp:34)
==8065==
==8065== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8065==    definitely lost: 40 bytes in 1 blocks

Comment: @Jon: Avoid this kind of memory management in the first place. Use `std::vector`.